# How do i add a mouseListener to a anonymous JLabel object?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, mouselistener

Currently I'm using a for-loop to populate the JPanel with numbers from 1-31

So basically, What I want to do is if let say i click on number 1, it will do show

```
System.out.println(1);
```

**Here's the code:**

```
     public class MonthPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

        public MonthPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(6,7));
            // Add headers
                // Use for-each loop.
                for (String header : headers) {
                  add(new JLabel(header));
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
                  add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(i)));
                }

            addMouseListener(this);
        }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            // What should i do in here to get a specific JLabel? 
               }
        }
}
```

Here's the picture

[image]

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 3) Instead of `JLabel` with `MouseListener` I would use `JButton` with `ActionListener` since the latter is more keyboard friendly.

Comment: 4) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 5) *"..let say i click on number 1, it will do show

`System.out.println(1);`"*  Another advantage of the `ActionListener`  - [`ActionEvent.getActionCommand()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand--) .. ;)

Comment: Let say I use JButton instead, how do I actually, get the specific JButton? because it is an anonymous object, plus how do i change its background color, since again it is an anonymous object

Comment: Where is that MCVE?  I will not give it further thought until you make the effort.

Comment: let me read MCVE first

Comment: What exactly are the errors of your edited version?

Comment: @MouseEvent there are no more errors. I have resolved it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the solution

First you have to add mouselistener in label which should have mouse adapter in brackets its because you only want to use mouse click method.

Than add mouseClicked method in it .

and than add you code in mouseClicked method.

Example:

```
    JLabel l = new JLabel("label");
    l.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            // Your Code Here

        }

    });
    add(l);
```

Comment: Tried your solution as well, but its giving me a lot of errors, see the edited version of the question

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding like that you can do something like

```
for (String header : headers) {
      JLabel lbl = new JLabel(header);
      lbl.addMouseListener(add ur listner);
      add(lbl);
}
```

In the mouseClicked event you can get the JLabel and print its text as follows

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(((JLabel) e.getSource()).getText());
}
```

In your code if you implement the `MouseListener` interface you must override all the abstract method in that. Otherwise it will not compile

Comment: Tried your solution, but its giving me a lot of errors, see the edited version of the question